# How to add scroll bar to tooltip of asp.net chart control

Tags: c#, html, css

I have created a pie chart using Chart Control in asp.net and to this I need to add huge data from database as tooltip on mouse hover. I am able to add the data to tooltip but this is covering the other elements in the screen and I am not able to see few data in the tooltip also. Is there a way to limit the height of tooltip and add scroll bar to it?

Comment: By "tooltip" are you referring to a native HTML `title=""` attribute - or something else?

Comment: Also, it's 2020. Why on earth are you still using WebForms?!?!

Comment: No..Not title="".I am using Chart.Series[0].Tooltip to add data..

Comment: New to Programming...So trying things out..

Comment: The `Chart.Series[0].Tooltip` you're referring to is a **server-side** feature that will be rendered to **client-side** HTML+JS+CSS. The `title=""` attribute is how most tooltips work on the client-side (though there are other approaches), that's why I was asking.

Comment: "New to Programming...So trying things out.." - I'll be frank: you're making a mistake. ASP.NET WebForms is an almost 20-year-old **obsolete** web-programming framework from 2001 that was designed around the presumption that a shallow mimicking of the VB6 programming model would work on the web. It didn't take long for Microsoft to realize that was a mistake and radically convert ASP.NET to use the now more common Action/Controller+View architecture in 2008 instead of the horrible Postback+View-State design. I urge you to stop using WebForms immediately otherwise you'll pick-up bad habits.

Comment: This the control i am using.You can see tooltip in series                                  
  <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
                <Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="Series1" Tooltip=""></asp:Series>
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
            </asp:Chart>